# Edge colorings of complete graphs without tricolored triangles

Tags: combinatorics, graphing-functions, coloring

Please prove the following theorem from *Gallai* :

> ***Theorem*** .In every coloring of a complete graph with three colors that avoiding rainbow triangle , at least one of the color classes
>   must be disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

("Rainbow triangle" means a triangle whose edges are colored with three different colors.)

This result goes back to a 1967 paper of Gallai.  It is proved, as Lemma A, in the following paper: "[Edge colorings of complete graphs without tricolored triangles](http://www.renyi.hu/~simonyi/galcol.ps)", András Gyárfás, Gábor Simony, Journal of Graph Theory, 46, #3, pages 211–216, July 2004, doi: 10.1002/jgt.20001 .